# How reduce size the header in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

i want reduce the header size.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i used this:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{1cm}
\makeatother
```

with that I could reduce the size

Comment: This works for me right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing wit beamers internal lengths, one can simply pass the height option to the `sidebar` outer theme by using `\PassOptionsToPackage{height=1cm}{beamerouterthemesidebar}` before the theme is loaded:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\PassOptionsToPackage{height=1cm}{beamerouterthemesidebar}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: you don't need to load the `graphicx` package with beamer

Comment: This does not work for me does it still work if I use a particular theme?